# Is there a way to update a native Android app with a React Native app without having to reinstall?

Tags: android, react-native

We've released a native Android app created using Android Studio, but have since change to using React Native. We created our first React Native release, however we're receiving an error message which states the new application is corrupt when attempting to install it while our original app is installed. If we uninstall the original app and then install our new React Native app, everything works great. We've used the same signing key, have made sure the package name and version name were identical, and incremented the version code by 1.

Has anyone been able to update from a native Android app to a React Native app without having to reinstall, and if so, are there additional parameters we need to consider?

Comment: look for the issue here or add a new one https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't find a similar existing issue so I created a new one.

Comment: possibly different version number can also create conflicts for same package name

Comment: I was able to solve my problem! I ensured that the values of the `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` variables within `build.gradle` matched what was used in our original native app. After that the update completed successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem! I ensured that the values of the `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` variables within `build.gradle` matched what was used in our original native app. After that the update completed successfully.

Comment: I did it, but unfortunately it did not

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem. I did these things

steps

- Make sure the `applicationId` is the same
- Insert previous app `signature` in new project
- `versionCode` more than previous app (in `app/build.gradle`)